# Why does the blackboard letters of the amsfont msbm have strange chardx values?

Tags: fonts, plain-tex, metafont, amsfonts

The font msbm which can be found under fonts/source/public/amsfonts/symbols in texlive has strange chardx width values set. If I run `mf "\mode=localfont; input msbm10"` I get the file msbm10.600gf. If I then run `gftype msbm10.600gf` I get a symbolic dump of the font data.

```
This is GFtype, Version 3.1 (TeX Live 2017/Debian) Options selected: Mnemonic output = false; pixel output = false. ' METAFONT output
2020.07.01:2334'

35: beginning of char 0

224: beginning of char 1
```

Further down in the file we have the width information for each character.

```
Postamble starts at byte 30141.
design size = 10485760 (10pt)
check sum = -2001332536
hppp = 544093 (8.3022)
vppp = 544093 (8.3022)
min m = -5, max m = 194
min n = -39, max n = 75
Character 0: dx 4259840 (65), width 815562 (64.57289), loc 35
Character 1: dx 4259840 (65), width 815562 (64.57289), loc 224
Character 2: dx 4259840 (65), width 815562 (64.57289), loc 413
```

dx is what metafont calls chardx, first comes the scaled value and then in parenthesis is the pixel value. The Metafont Book describes it as such:

*"chardx" and "chardy" represent horizontal and vertical escapement in units of pixels. (Some typesetting systems use both of these device-dependent amounts to change their current position on a page, just after typesetting each character. Other systems, like the dvi software associated with TeX, assume that "chardy"=0 but use "chardx" as the horizontal escapement whenever a horizontal movement by "chardx" does not cause the subsequent position to drift too far from the device-independent position defined by accumulated "charwd" values.*

Next comes the width of the character which Metafont calls charwd it is in units of the design size scaled by 2^20. In the parenthesis following is the value converted to pixels. Normally the chardx pixel value should be the same as the charwd pixel value but rounded to an integer, but the font designer can tweak the chardx value to better suit a low resolution device, however you would expect them to not deviate by more than one pixel. In the blackboard letters in msbm they deviate by a large amount which can be seen in the following. Blackboard letter A is character 65 and Z is character 90, and the lowercase k is character 124.

```
Character 61: dx 5439488 (83), width 1048579 (83.02225), loc 13792
Character 62: dx 4259840 (65), width 815562 (64.57289), loc 14616
Character 63: dx 4259840 (65), width 815562 (64.57289), loc 14815
Character 64: dx 3014656 (46), width 582544 (46.12347), loc 15066
Character 65: dx 2424832 (37), width 757307 (59.96051), loc 20334
Character 66: dx 2490368 (38), width 699053 (55.34819), loc 20637
Character 67: dx 2555904 (39), width 757307 (59.96051), loc 21048
Character 68: dx 2621440 (40), width 757307 (59.96051), loc 21349
Character 69: dx 2686976 (41), width 699053 (55.34819), loc 21770
Character 70: dx 2752512 (42), width 640798 (50.7358), loc 22133
Character 71: dx 2818048 (43), width 815562 (64.57289), loc 22456
Character 72: dx 2883584 (44), width 815562 (64.57289), loc 22823
Character 73: dx 2949120 (45), width 407781 (32.28645), loc 23254
Character 74: dx 3014656 (46), width 524290 (41.51115), loc 23477
Character 75: dx 3080192 (47), width 815562 (64.57289), loc 23762
Character 76: dx 3145728 (48), width 699053 (55.34819), loc 24161
Character 77: dx 3211264 (49), width 990325 (78.40993), loc 24430
Character 78: dx 3276800 (50), width 757307 (59.96051), loc 25021
Character 79: dx 3342336 (51), width 815562 (64.57289), loc 25408
Character 80: dx 3407872 (52), width 640798 (50.7358), loc 25843
Character 81: dx 3473408 (53), width 815562 (64.57289), loc 26154
Character 82: dx 3538944 (54), width 757307 (59.96051), loc 26641
Character 83: dx 3604480 (55), width 582544 (46.12347), loc 27060
Character 84: dx 3670016 (56), width 699053 (55.34819), loc 27377
Character 85: dx 3735552 (57), width 757307 (59.96051), loc 27676
Character 86: dx 3801088 (58), width 757307 (59.96051), loc 28021
Character 87: dx 3866624 (59), width 1048579 (83.02225), loc 28336
Character 88: dx 3932160 (60), width 757307 (59.96051), loc 28901
Character 89: dx 3997696 (61), width 757307 (59.96051), loc 29218
Character 90: dx 4063232 (62), width 699053 (55.34819), loc 29503
Character 91: dx 10289152 (157), width 1980650 (156.81985), loc 15333

Character 123: dx 3604480 (55), width 699053 (55.34819), loc 19590
Character 124: dx 4128768 (63), width 582544 (46.12347), loc 29810
Character 125: dx 2949120 (45), width 566525 (44.85516), loc 19769
Character 126: dx 2949120 (45), width 566525 (44.85516), loc 20014
Character 127: dx 2359296 (36), width 450016 (35.63045), loc 20245
The file had 123 characters altogether.
```

Not only do the chardx values not match the charwd values for these letters, they follow an increasing sequence and do not seem to have much to do with the actual width of the character. Furthermore, if I generate the font in proof mode by running `mf "\mode=proof; input msbm10"` followed by `gftodvi msbm10.2602gf` and then open msbm10.dvi the blackboard letters in the font show a strange looking grid while the other characters do not.

[image: Proof letter A]

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but considering *“use "chardx" […] whenever [it] does not cause the subsequent position to drift too far from […] accumulated "charwd" values”* — so does it mean that when the chardx values are (apparently) so meaningless as they here, they do not matter?

Comment: Well, as I understand it, if we start at an x pos of 0 and if the max_drift is set to 2 pixels as in dvitype and charwd for A is say 29.9 pixels and chardx is 50 pixels then the "correct" x position after typesetting A should be 30. But using chardx would make it 50 which is more than 2 pixels away from 30 so x will instead be set to 32. Now if we try to typeset another A the "correct" position should be be round(29.9*2)=60. Adding chardx to 32 will be 82 which is again more than 2 pixels wrong so x will be set to 62.